# Django CBV: Easy access to url parameters in get_context_data()?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I understand that the standard way of accessing named url parameters in a custom `get_context_data()` method is through `self.kwargs`.

However, the `self.kwargs` syntax becomes awkward, especially when handling a significant number of parameters.  So, I've been resorting to something like this at the top of every `get_context_data()` method -- just to get easy-to-handle local variables:

```python
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = [self.kwargs[x] for x in ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5']]
    # do stuff with var1, var2, ...
    # instead of self.kwargs['var1'], self.kwargs['var2'], ...
```

This is ugly and a pain, but it ultimately makes things a lot easier to work with and read.

Is there a simple way to clean it up and get named parameters into local variables?  Short of overriding the `get()` method, subclassing Django's generic views, etc.?  I suspect I'm just missing some extremely basic, fundamental python concept here.

Here is the default `get()` method that calls `get_context_data()` in case it's helpful to reference here:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**UPDATE:**

My mistake, the calling `get()` method is actually as follows (The generic `FormView` is being subclassed in this case).  Unfortunately the kwargs that are passed into `get_context_data()` are not the same as `self.kwargs`:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Many thanks!

Comment: No, you are not missing any fundamental concept. But reading from dicts can indeed get on one's nerves. That is why there are a bunch of packages at PyPI that convert a ``dict`` with only ``str`` keys into an object with accordingly named (virtual) attributes. I sometimes use [``dictns``](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dictns) for that purpose. Nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If kwargs passed to `get_context_data` is the same as `self.kwargs`, You could do this:

```
def get_context_data(self, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, **kwargs):
    # do stuff with var1, var2, ...
```

EDIT: you could override the get method to pass the kwargs in. I know its not elegant, but it would work. You could make a mixin to use in multiple classes.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs))
```

Other than that, I really can't think of a better way. Your original solution might be best. I usually just access `self.kwargs['...']` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this doesn't work with `FormView`, where the kwargs passed are not the same as `self.kwargs`. I updated the question.

Comment: Ah, well I can't think of a great way then. I did edit my answer with some more thoughts though. Sorry I can't help any more than that.

Comment: No worries, and thanks for taking a look! Your solution works for, say, `TemplateView` where kwargs == self.kwargs.  This whole issue is just a minor gripe on my part anyways.

Comment: P.S. You'd have to override both `form_invalid()` _and_ `get()` just to get `FormView` working this way.  Heh, what a mess. I wonder why those methods don't pass kwargs to `get_context_data()`.

Comment: Yes I figured there would be another method to override. I think it's too much hassle. If I were you I would just stick to your original solution. Or maybe create another method which you call from get_context_data. And pass self.kwargs to that new method. I usually don't like to do too much processing in get_context_data anyway.

Comment: You're totally right -- I should pull all the processing into a new method. And I think I can live with the list comprehension bit to stuff kwargs into local variables. Thanks again!